# How to solve this limit of a function? ($\cos^3x$)

Tags: limits, functions, trigonometry

So I'm having trouble with the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{1-\cos^3x}{x\,\sin x}}$$

Sorry to bother again, but I was never good at solving limits.
Really, I don't know what to do with that $\cos^3 x$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please, tell us first what you tried up to now. We are willing to help but not to do your homework.

Comment: At $x=0$ we have $0/0$, so the first thing to do would be to look at L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Well, I just don't know what to do with that cos3⁡x with xsinx in nominator.

Comment: I'm trying to get something like sinx/x or x/sinx

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1-\cos^3(x)}{x\sin(x)}
&=(1+\cos(x)+\cos^2(x))\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x\sin(x)}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is just a hint?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Was a hint required? I can remove the preface, if that makes you happy.

Comment: I just thought that the OP should have shown more own effort, in particular since he had a similar problem solved for him an hour ago. But on reconsideration, I do not care that much.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: ah, I did not see the previous question. I might have been less forthcoming.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: I have removed all but the first step, which addresses the question of what can be done about $\cos^3(x)$, but not much else. Unfortunately, it appears the OP may have already read the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Hint : write $\cos^3(x)$ as $\cos(x)(1-\sin^2(x))$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Using the series expansion of $\cos$, try working from the following:
$$\cos^3x=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{4!}x^4-\dots\right)^3=\;\;??$$

Comment: I don't think that this is going to help him without any more explanation. He could ask himself: why is $cos(x)^3 = (1-\frac12 x^2+...)^3$? Why can I use this?

Comment: @Ale That's a good suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $\cos^3 x = (1-\sin^2 x)\cos x$ you find
$$
\frac{1-\cos^3 x}{x\sin x} = \frac{1-\cos x}{x\sin x}+\frac{\sin^2 x\cos x}{x\sin x}
$$
The last term goes to 1 as $x\to 0$ (use $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 1$), whereas for the first term u can multiply by $\frac{1+\cos x}{1 + \cos x}$ and you see that it goes to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $$\frac{\color{#C00000}{1-}\cos^3(x)}{x\sin(x)}=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x\sin(x)} +\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(x)}{x\sin(x)}$$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll edit that.